# Why I see all values of [Closed Date] even when it has been filtered by the measure?

Tags: dax

I want to calculate the distinct cases ID's that have been opened in the last 30 days (given a selected Date), and then get only the ones that have been closed in a date later from the selected.

My model is simple: `Date -----> Fact on Fact[Open Date] = Dates[Date]`

I wrote this measure althought I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve this.

```
0 - 30 Days = 

VAR _sdate = SELECTEDVALUE('Dates'[Date])

RETURN

CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact[ID])
,DATESINPERIOD('Dates'[Date]), _sdate, -30, DAY)
,FILTER(ALL('Fact'[Closed Date]), 'Fact[Closed Date] > _sdate)
```

If I put the measure in a table, the result is the expected. If I add others Fact attributes (like `[Country]`) the result gets splited across those attributes as expected.

[image]

But when I put in the `[Closed Date]` column this happens:

[image]

I can see all the values as if no context was applied.

Why?